# conleyreg() for panel data

Tags: econometrics, applied-econometrics, r, spatial-economics

With panel data, how does conleyreg() correct for spatial correlation and autocorrelation within units over time? More specifically, why do my standard errors change when I specify 'unit' and 'time' in conleyreg()?

```
### Toy example
n <- 100
# Generate cross-sectional example data
data <- rnd_locations(n, output_type = "data.frame")
data$y <- sample(c(0, 1), n, replace = TRUE)
data$x1 <- stats::runif(n, -50, 50)
data$time <- rep(1:10, each = 10)
data$unit <- rep(1:10, times = 10)
```

```
### Without specifying unit and time
> conleyreg(y ~ x1, data, 1000, lat = "lat", lon = "lon")
Checking spatial attributes
Estimating model
Estimating distance matrix and addressing spatial correlation

t test of coefficients:

               Estimate  Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.43011678  0.05297974  8.1185 1.416e-12 ***
x1          -0.00028297  0.00174242 -0.1624    0.8713    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

```
### Specifying unit and time
> conleyreg(y ~ x1, data, 1000, unit = "unit", time = "time", lat = "lat", lon = "lon") # not FE --> changes SE
Checking spatial attributes
Balanced panel identified
Estimating model
Estimating distance matrix and addressing spatial correlation
Not addressing serial correlation because lag_cutoff is zero

t test of coefficients:

               Estimate  Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.43011678  0.04951070  8.6874 8.483e-14 ***
x1          -0.00028297  0.00181382 -0.1560    0.8763    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```